# If I buy a power adapter from the online Australian Apple Store, will it match Australian outlets?

Tags: charging, power

I want a power adapter for a MacBook Air that matches Australian outlets (without a separate adapter).  It seems reasonable that if I buy such a thing from http://www.apple.com/au, it will have the right outlet format.

Unfortunately, there's no language to that effect on the product page, and if I add it to cart there's no indication that the adapter won't be US-format.  Will adapters purchased from http://www.apple.com/au be Australian format?

Comment: No, remember everything is opposite in Australia so it'll match China's outlet... Watch out for the Spider too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at: [Apple World Travel Adapter Kit](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD837AM/A/apple-world-travel-adapter-kit)

If you get the adaptor kit it works with your existing power supply. You just pop off the end you have, and slide on the new end. It's just changing out the prongs for the correct one needed.

Also works with most other Apple products.

This isn't like a normal international adaptor which sits between the socket and the existing plug - it replaces the existing plug.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you buy from the Australian Apple Store is going to have an Australian power outlet plug. I'd be more wary about buying from Australian 'suppliers' from eBay or similar. You'll probably run into fake chargers there (even with Australian power plugs). There's a good list of differences in the article "[Real vs. Fake Apple Power Adapters: 4 Signs of a Fake](https://www.verified.org/articles/guides/real-vs-fake-apple-power-adapters) from Verified.org.

I unknowingly bought one years ago, and it is still working but does get a bit too hot for my liking so I'm always been a bit suss on them.